# How to setup the UIWebView to make the page auto zoom in and fit in whole window?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, webkit

I use UIWebView to load a html page which contains only one SVG image file with below code:

```
self.webView = [UIWebView new];
self.webView.opaque = YES;
self.webView.frame = self.view.frame;
[_webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
self.webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

self.webView.delegate=self;

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

and I take the a screen capture as below, I want to make the image file can be auto zoom in to fit the whole window when View is shown, currently I had to double tab the image to make it happen.

[image]

and belwo is what I expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.5;"];
[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```